# Отличие операторов RESTRICT и NO ACTION в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В чем отличие RESTRICT от NO ACTION в mySQL (при использовании внешнего ключа)?

Comment: Да вроде [ничем](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809954), т.к. в mysql проверка FK constraints происходит сразу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально в стандартном SQL:

- `NO ACTION` — при удалении или обновлении записей из таблицы предке
  связи с таблицами потомками игнорируются, до закрытия транзакции. Таким образом, внутри одной транзакции можно сначала обновить или удалить записи в таблице предке, до внесения изменений в таблицы потомки. Работает это только с отложенными ключами.
- `RESTRICT` — при попытке удаления или обновления записей из таблицы предка,
  при наличии связанных записей в таблице потомка будет выдана ошибка.

Но в MySQL параметры `RESTRICT` и `NO ACTION` идентичны.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: А `NO ACTION` в стандарте (не в mysql) точно "игнорирование" означает? Вроде как там должна быть отложенная проверка. Т.е. `NO ACTION` - проверка выполняется в конце операции, в то время как `RESTRICT` - в начале

Comment: @BOPOH вы правы, исправил в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT.